# C++ cache that evicts items based on their 'value'

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, caching

I would like to implement a cache in C++ that is templated, and memory-limited.
I can quite easily just evice the first item when the size gets to a certain limit, based on some rudimentary value like
`memlimit / (sizeof(TKey) + sizeof(TVal))`

But I would ideally like to apply some logic so that the "least valuable" item is evicted.
My thinking was that the logic would be something along the lines of this:

- When there is a cache miss, calculate it, but also remember how long it took to calculate it. Store this time (somewhere).
- When there is a cache hit, increment the number of times that that cached value has been accessed.
- When the memory limit is reached and another item wants to be stored, evict the *N* items with the least "worth", where "worth" is defined as the time it took to calculate, multiplied by the number of times it's been accessed.

Can anyone suggest whether this logic is reasonable?

This is inspired by Project Euler problems but not specific to a certain one of them - I want to make a generic component, and it would be a quite nice generic tool to have for other things.

Is there something off the shelf that might fit?

I am starting off like

```
template<class TKey, class TValue>
public class cache
{
    public:
        std::map<TKey, TValue> values;

        void encache(const TKey& key, const TKey& value)
        {
            if(values.insert(std::pair<TKey, TValue>(key, value))
            {
                if(values.size() > 10000000 /* some limit */ )
                {
                     // evict the 'worst' values - ???
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but not sure of the best data structure to use to store the values, and what the eviction algorithm should look like.

Comment: the easiest way to invalidate your cache is to call values.clear() when the cash becomes big

Comment: Take a look at [page replacement strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Page_replacement_algorithms).